# Вырезать последнюю букву из слова java

Tags: java

Хочу сделать игру "города"  на java (человек вводит название города, а программа выдает другой, название которого начинается на последнюю букву введенного ранее) . Сейчас застрял на моменте отделения последней буквы. Крутил Split по-разному, но не получается сделать так, чтобы отделялась последняя буква. Кто-нибудь знает , как правильно это сделать?

Comment: `str.substring(0, str.length() - 1)`?

Comment: `str.charAt(str.length() - 1);`

Comment: @iksuy ваш вариант помог, спасибо!

Comment: У вас очень неоднозначная формулировка. Судя по всему вы хотите **получить** последнюю букву, но зачем-то используете слово "отделить", вводя отвечающих в заблуждение. В игре Города нет никакого смысла "отделять" последнюю букву. Таким образом все ответы с `substring()` вам не подходят.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char letter = str.charAt(str.length() - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас Строка то ответ такой :

```
string= string.substring(0, string.length() - 1);
```